# Powershell While loop doesn't work as expected

Tags: powershell

I can't understand why the While loop in the bottom example starts again from "Write-Host "No db, please type filenames"" when I answer "n" to the second prompt inside the While, instead to skip the while block

Any idea?

```
$GetDb = Get-SqlDatabase -name "Data1" -ServerInstance "server\insta"

if ($GetDb) {
  Write-Host "Db exists!"
}
else {
  Write-Host "No db, please type filenames"
  $Prompt = Read-Host "Do you want add files?(y/n)"
    While ($Prompt-match "y") {
    $file1 = Read-Host "Type filename"
    $Prompt = Read-Host "Do you want to add more files?"
    }
}
```

Thank you

db

Comment: The loop works as expected for me, may be run a new instance of powershell ISE and check.

Comment: @VasilSvilenovNikolov I tried with a new instance of ISE, but nothing to do.
It sill returns to the else